# How to change font of part of a rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I want to allow the user to change the font while using the app. For example, my user typed the first paragraph in arial font, 12 pt;  then next paragraph he can type in another font with a different size.

The problem I am facing is when I change a font, the entire font of the text field is changing.

Code is:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    richTextBox1.Font = 
        new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Italic);
}
```

Comment: Is this the [winforms richtext box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [WPF richtext box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700102/how-to-change-the-font-of-multiple-sizes-in-richtextbox-in-c/26701034#26701034)

Comment: Also, see [Changing font for RichTextBox without losing formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16307021/719186)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it coded now, it is referencing the entire `richTextBox1`. You can try using `richTextBox1.SelectionFont =`... to change the font of just the section you have chosen.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont(v=vs.110).aspx